# Character name help (beautiful?)

Tags: names

I was told my wife's name means "beautiful" and that in English it sounds like "Jenny" (I thought it was zhenyi, but apparently not). Was hoping to get the correct spelling and characters for future reference. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

真怡 - zhen1yi2 - really happy.

Hope this helps.